# Is there a way to play a specific tone using python3?

Tags: python, windows, pycharm

I'm working on a python3 project (in PyCharm, using Windows 10) and I'm trying to play a series of tones and save them all to a mp3 file.

I can get it to play a series of notes with winsound:

```
import winsound
while True:
    winsound.Beep(1000, 1000)
```

But I can't save it.

All help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save output to a file, rather than just play it, probably the most ideal way of doing this is to generate midi files. There are a few packages that can help you create midi files in a similar way.

This example uses the package called `mido`

```py
from mido import Message, MidiFile, MidiTrack

mid = MidiFile()
track = MidiTrack()
mid.tracks.append(track)

track.append(Message('note_on', note=64, velocity=64, time=32))

mid.save('new_song.mid')
```

You can convert midi files to MP3s easily if needed (many programs or even online tools can do this) although, midi files are generally well-supported in most applications.

[See also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64839411/5747944)

Although perhaps dated, you can also check the [PythonInMusic](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonInMusic#MIDI_Mania) wiki for references to more MIDI and other audio libraries.

Alternatively, you can use a separate program to record your audio output when running your python script using `winsound`.